# Lock KDE workspace from terminal qdbus command

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu

I know qdbus, but coulnd't find a command for it.
Is there a way to lock the entire workspace / all widgets from terminal?

I'm on Kubuntu 12.04 KDE 4.8.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a command to lock the screen

```
qdbus org.kde.krunner /ScreenSaver Lock
```

is that what You wanted?